# Find the missing number group by category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find the missing batchNo group by each category 
I try this and it work but I get all the missing number for all categories 
how to group by the data ?

```
 CREATE TABLE #tmp  (BatchNo INT, Category VARCHAR(15))
    INSERT INTO #tmp
    SELECT 94, 'A01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 97, 'A01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 100, 'A02'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 105, 'A02'
```

---

```
  declare @valmax INT, @valmin INT, @i INT;

  select @valmax=max(BatchNo) from #tmp;
  select @valmin=min(BatchNo) from #tmp;


  set @i=@valmin;
  while (@i<@valmax) begin
    if (not exists(select * from #tmp where BatchNo=@i)) begin
       --   SELECT @i, Category FROM #tmp GROUP BY Category  
       SELECT @i

    end;
    set @i=@i+1
  end;
```

the out put shold be like

```
95      A01
96      A01

101     A02
102     A02
103     A02
104     A02
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like a job for SQL.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Definitely not a job for SQL.

Comment: can u please help me

Comment: What would the desired output look like?

Comment: u can see the output

Comment: How many categories can there by, and is it fine if you do it per category instead of having all the answers in one go?

Comment: it 10 categories  I just give u a small exemple of my table

Comment: @New_World Did any of the answers solve your problem? If not please tell why not, or if any did, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks @jpw you are my savior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by joining with a number table. This query uses the`spt_values`table and should work:

```
;with cte as (
    select category , min(batchno) min_batch, max(batchno) max_batch
    from #tmp
    group by category
)
select number, category
from master..spt_values
cross join cte
where type = 'p'
  and number > min_batch
  and number < max_batch
group by category, number
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23107)

Note that this table only has a sequence of numbers `0-2047`so if your`BatchNo`can be higher you need another source for the query (could be another table or a recursive cte); something like this would work:

```
;with 
    cte (category, min_batch, max_batch) as (
       select category , min(batchno), max(batchno)
       from #tmp
       group by category
    ), 
    numbers (number, max_number) as (
       select 1 as number, (select MAX(batchno) from #tmp) max_number
       union all
       select number + 1, max_number
       from numbers
       where number < max_number
    )

select number, category
from numbers cross join cte
where number > min_batch
  and number < max_batch
group by category, number
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amended my answer. Probably better than using spt_values just because there is a limit. Thanks for jpw for a better way of doing it

```
    Declare @Start int
    Declare @End int
    Select @Start = Min(BatchNo), @End = Max(BatchNo) from #tmp;

    with nums as (
          select @Start as n
          union all
          select n+1
          from nums
          where n < @End
         )
    Select n, Category from nums
    cross join #tmp t
    where n > (select Min(BatchNo) from #tmp where Category = t.Category group by Category) 
    and n < (select Max(BatchNo) from #tmp where Category = t.Category group by Category) 
    group by category, n
```